# dragging while holding ctrl (control) key doesn't work in OpenLayers3?

Tags: openlayers, pan

When I hold down the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (control) key on my keyboard and attempt to pan any OL3 map with my mouse, the pan doesn't happen.

Because of the particular needs of my application, I need panning to work when the ctrl key is held down, just as it does when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not held down.

I couldn't see anywhere in the OL3 documentation about ctrl-drag being treated specially, so I don't know where to look to disable this behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some tests and the behaviour is not exact the same, but it does the job. [Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXTHxT?p=preview).

It is a clone of [`ol.interaction.DragPan.handleDragEvent_`](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/f5cd9a3ebac748d248e04b30688db447435d23ab/src/ol/interaction/dragpaninteraction.js#L72)

It is done on `pointermove` event:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt){

    if(evt.dragging && evt.originalEvent.ctrlKey){


        var centroid = [evt.originalEvent.clientX, evt.originalEvent.clientY];
        var lastCentroid = interactions.getArray()[dragpan_index].lastCentroid;

        if(lastCentroid){
            var deltaX = lastCentroid[0] - centroid[0];
            var deltaY = centroid[1] - lastCentroid[1];

            var center = [deltaX, deltaY];
            var view = map.getView();
            ol.coordinate.scale(center, view.getResolution());
            ol.coordinate.rotate(center, view.getRotation());
            ol.coordinate.add(center, view.getCenter());
            center = view.constrainCenter(center);
            map.render();
            view.setCenter(center);

        }
        interactions.getArray()[dragpan_index].lastCentroid = centroid;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to put this together. It helped me immensely, not only with this problem, but another custom behavior I wanted while panning. I modified your approach to not create the default DragPan interaction at all (i.e., my map has no DragPan interaction per se, and I just do all that needs to be done in this on pointermove function).

Comment: Glad to help! You're welcome.